# a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Node<int> *"C/C++(513)

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, class-template

I have a linked list that contains a pointer to the first and last node and size which indicates how many nodes are there in the list.
I have a function that returns the first node.

I want to be able to change the m_data in the first node using `queue1.front() = 3;`. However, I am getting

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Node<int>*’
```

error while compiling

```cpp
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
    Node(const T& t);
    ~Node() = default;            // Destructor
    Node(const Node&) = default;  // Copy Constructor set to default
    Node& operator=(const Node&) =
        default;  // Assignment operator set to default
    T& getData();
    const T& getData() const;
    Node* getNext();
    void setNext(Node<T>* newNext);

private:
    T m_data;
    Node* m_nextNode;
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& t) {
    this->m_data = t;
    this->m_nextNode = nullptr;
}
```

```cpp
template <class T>
class Queue {
public:
    static const int SIZE_EMPTY = 0;
    Queue();
    ~Queue();                       // Destructor
    Queue(const Queue&) = default;  // Copy Constructor set to default
    Queue& operator=(const Queue&) =
        default;  // Assignment operator set to default
    void pushBack(const T& t);
    Node<T>*& front();
    const Node<T>*& front() const;
    void popFront();
    int size() const;
    class EmptyQueue {};

private:
    Node<T>* m_head;
    Node<T>* m_tail;
    int m_size;
};

template <class T>
Node<T>*& Queue<T>::front() {
    if (this->m_size == Queue<T>::SIZE_EMPTY) {
        throw Queue<T>::EmptyQueue();
    }
    return this->m_head;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::pushBack(const T& t) {
    this->m_size += 1;
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(t);
    this->m_tail = newNode;
    if (this->m_size == 1) {
        this->m_head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node<T>* tempNode = this->m_head;
        while (tempNode->getNext()) {
            tempNode = tempNode->getNext();
        }
        tempNode->setNext(newNode);
    }
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
    Queue<int> queue1;
    queue1.pushBack(1);
    queue1.front() = 3;
}
```

Comment: Compiling these snippets does not reproduce the compilation error you get. Add enough code to make it reproduce the error. Remove the functions not needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo updated the question, i hope this is what you meant

Comment: Much better. I completed it to make it a [mre].

Comment: You're re-inventing the wheel – there's already `std::list` (doubly linked) and `std::forward_list` (singly linked) as well as `std::queue` based upon a container (`std::deque` as default, but you could use one of the lists as well). It's fine if homework, afterwards you should be using the standard containers, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua it's for homework, and i can't use anything in std, i need to initialize everything including iterators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queue<T>::front()` is returning a `Node<T>*&` when it should return a `T&`.

Example:

```
template <class T>
T& Queue<T>::front() {
    if (this->m_size == Queue<T>::SIZE_EMPTY) {
        throw Queue<T>::EmptyQueue();
    }
    return m_head->getData();
}

template <class T>
const T& Queue<T>::front() const {
    if (this->m_size == Queue<T>::SIZE_EMPTY) {
        throw Queue<T>::EmptyQueue();
    }
    return m_head->getData();
}
```

You also need to make the same change in the class definition:

```
template <class T>
class Queue {
public:
    //...
    T& front();
    const T& front() const;
    //...
};
```

Comment: I've tried to make front return the m_data before and it worked, but i need front to return the whole node for future use implementing iterators, is there any way to do conversion to solve the problem

Comment: @KareemAraide For the iterator to front, the member is usually called `begin()`. Maybe, you could base `front()` upon `begin()` later (to reduce code duplication). I don't think that `front()` should expose things which actually should be internals.

Comment: @KareemAraide ... and a Node* isn't going to be useful as an iterator. You'll need a class encapsulating the Node*.  The actual Nodes are rarely exposed to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that `Queue<T>::front` returns a `Node<T>*` by reference and so by writing `queue1.front() = 3;` you're trying to assign an `int` to an `Node<int>*`.

```
queue1.front() = 3;
```

In the above statement, the left hand side result has a type `Node<int>*` but the right hand side is `3` which is an `int`. Thus the type on the left hand side and right hand side mismatch and since there is no implicit conversion from an `int` to a `Node<int>*`, you get the mentioned error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Node<int>*
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do conversion between them but still getting the same compiling error